# Animation with Tween JS - Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, createjs, tween

I am  creating an animation with Tween JS that should turn some light bulbs on and off.
There are overall 17 light bulbs, the animation for the first and second works fine but after the second light bulb goes off there comes this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

This is the code for the animation:

```
var do_the_lights = function (light_bulbs_arr, repeat_nr,f)
{
  if(++repeat_nr < light_bulbs_arr.length)
  createjs.Tween.get(light_bulbs_arr[repeat_nr]).to({alpha:0},2000).to({alpha:1},2000).call(f,[light_bulbs_arr,repeat_nr]);
do_the_lights(this.light_bulbs_arr,-1,do_the_lights);
```

In the array light_bulbs_arr are bitmap images from the light bulbs when they are off.

```
for( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
  var light_bulb = new createjs.Bitmap(images.light_bulb);
  this.light_bulbs_arr[i] = light_bulb;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The function is not being passed on to the Tween in the `call`. I answered this on the CreateJS forum. http://community.createjs.com/discussions/tweenjs/584-animation-with-tween-js-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined

Comment: hey Lanny, thank you for helping me! Pleas set your comment as a response so that I can accept and upvote it!
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did not pass the function onto the next iteration in the call().

```
.call(f,[light_bulbs_arr,repeat_nr]);

// SHOULD BE

.call(f,[light_bulbs_arr,repeat_nr, f]); // Note the 3rd param
```